# Determinant of lower triangular matrix is equal to zero

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to solve a system of linear equations $\bf{Ax=b}$ where the matrix $\bf{A}$ is lower triangular.  Now if $\det(\bf{A}) = 0$, does this imply that I cannot solve for $\bf{x}$?  Under which conditions can I solve for $\bf{x}$?

Comment: In general, $\det(A) = 0$ implies there is no inverse matrix.  So, we can not solve by multiplying both sides by the inverse to get
$$x = A^{-1} b.$$  But, it doesn't mean it can not be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't. The most you can say from the fact that $\det A = 0$ is that either there are no solutions, or there are infinitely many solutions (assuming that the matrix is over an infinite field such as $\mathbb{R}$). For the conditions under which you can solve for $\mathbf{x}$, you can look at the [Kronecker-Capelli theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem) and the [Fredholm's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm%27s_theorem).